# Bootstrap.php required while running vendor/bin/phpunit

Tags: php, cakephp, phpunit

I'm on CakePHP using PHPUnit but I can't test my tests because of that error :

> PHP Warning: 
>   require(/home/etd/MonApplication/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/config/bootstrap.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/etd/MonApplication/config/bootstrap.php on line 30
>
> PHP Fatal error:   require(): Failed opening required
>   '/home/etd/MonApplication/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/config/bootstrap.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in
>   /home/etd/MonApplication/config/bootstrap.php on line 30

This is my line 30 :

> require CORE_PATH . 'config' . DS . 'bootstrap.php';

Any Help? THX

Comment: You should really have that file there. Don't know why it wouldn't be. You can get it [from the repo](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/tree/master/config) if `composer install` or the like doesn't fix it.

Comment: Your vendor folder should indeed be full of directories... Maybe there was a problem with your installation